# Timedelta multiply with float in python

Tags: python, datetime, multiplication, timedelta

I have two dates and can calculate timedelta as usual.

But I want to calculate some percent with resulting timedelta:

```
full_time = (100/percentage) * timdelta
```

But it seems that it can only multiplying with interegs.

How can I use `float` instead of `int` as multiplier?

Example:

```
percentage     = 43.27
passed_time    = fromtimestamp(fileinfo.st_mtime) - fromtimestamp(fileinfo.st_ctime)
multiplier     = 100 / percentage   # 2.3110700254217702796394730760342
full_time      = multiplier * passed_time # BUG: here comes exception
estimated_time = full_time - passed_time
```

If is used `int(multiplier)` — accuracy suffers.

Comment: You're right, timedelta just supports multiplication or division with intergers, but why you don't perform the math operations in sequence step by step? `full_time = passed_time * 100 / int(percentage)`

Comment: @Colin O'Coal, because of accuracy: `2 != 2.3131`. Compare: `571 * 2 = 1142` (**19**,03(3) minutes); `571 * 2.3131 = 1320,7801` (**22**,0130016(6) minutes). Difference is about **3 minutes** (!)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can convert to total seconds and back again:

```
full_time = timedelta(seconds=multiplier * passed_time.total_seconds())
```

[`timedelta.total_seconds`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) is available from Python 2.7; on earlier versions use

```
def timedelta_total_seconds(td):
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / float(10**6)
```

Comment: just thank you! Honestly I forgot about `timedelta` constructor. And thank you for "back compatibility" )

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=datetime.timedelta(minutes=42).total_seconds() * 0.8)
# => datetime.timedelta(0, 2016)
```